# How can I handle a bytearray message in a Spring Integration Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm having some issues with Spring Integration.

I have an error channel that is supposed to consume an error dedicated queue in case other flows have an error, this handler allows us to log some important data in a very specific format, and then the message is discarded.

The problem is, that this flow is configured to receive a specific message type, like a FailedMessage class.

Whenever the message is consumed, I get a class cast exception saying that `[B cannot be cast to FailedMessage`.

So, after doing some research I implemented the following transformer:

```
    private FailedMessage parseFailedMessage(byte[] genericMessage){
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(genericMessage);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            return (FailedMessage) is.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An unexpected error occurred parsing FailedMessage", e);
        }
    }
```

And the IntegrationFlow spec is :

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow(XmlMessageTransformer transformer) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("ErrorChannel")
                .transform(this::parseFailedMessage)
                .<FailedMessage>handle((p, h) -> {
                    processFailedMessage(p, transformer);
                    return p;
                })
                .channel("discard")
                .get();
    }
```

Is this an acceptable way to handle this kind of message or there's a way to automatize the transform step?

Comment: Can we see, please, more stack trace to determine the place where you exactly got that ClassCast? Either way the error channel receives an `ErrorMessage` which payload is an `Exception`. So, I'm not sure how you expect a `byte[]`...